# Clip-path animation not working for the second time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I'm trying to build a expanded menu using jQuery and css animations, so far the animations runs smothly the first time but the second time they're played they dont work.
I've seen people doing a similar menu using javascript classes but I need to keep this simple because this code will be maintened by people that don't know much about js

```js
$('#button').on('click',function(){
  if(!$('.menu').hasClass('stay')){
    $('.menu').removeClass('close')
    $('.menu').addClass('open')
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.menu').addClass('stay')
      $('.menu').removeClass('open')
    },1000)
  }else{
    $('.menu').removeClass('stay')
    $('.menu').addClass('close')
  }
});
```

```css
*{
  font-family: monospace;
}
.menu{
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  width: min-content;
  padding: .5rem;
  clip-path: circle(10% at 22px 22px);
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: large;
  font-weigth: 800;
  padding: 1rem;
}
li{
  border-bottom: solid 1px white;
  padding-top: .4rem;
  padding-bottom: .4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button{
  border: solid 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
.open{
  animation: 1s circle-path;
}
.stay{
  clip-path: circle(100%);
}
.close{
  animation: 1s circle-path reverse;
}
@keyframes circle-path {
  100% { clip-path: circle(100%); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <button id="button">+</button>
  <ul>
    <li>Chat</li>
    <li>Video</li>
    <li>Minuta</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use an animation to open and close the menu. Just toggle a class. You can simplify your code like this:

```js
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('active')
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.menu {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  width: min-content;
  padding: .5rem;
  clip-path: circle(10% at 22px 22px);
  transition: 1s clip-path;
}

.active {
  clip-path: circle(100%);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: large;
  font-weigth: 800;
  padding: 1rem;
}

li {
  border-bottom: solid 1px white;
  padding-top: .4rem;
  padding-bottom: .4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  border: solid 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <button id="button">+</button>
  <ul>
    <li>Chat</li>
    <li>Video</li>
    <li>Minuta</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```